# Why is it not OK to put a xsl:value-of into a fo:block?

Tags: intellij-idea, xslt, xsd, xsl-fo

I have the following XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output media-type="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root/branch">

        <fo:root>

            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                                       page-height="29.7cm"
                                       page-width="21cm"
                                       margin-top="1cm"
                                       margin-bottom="2cm"
                                       margin-left="2.5cm"
                                       margin-right="2.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                    <fo:block font-size="12pt"
                              font-family="sans-serif"
                              line-height="15pt"
                              space-after.optimum="3pt"
                              text-align="justify">
                        <xsl:value-of select="branch/greenLeave"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="branch/yellowLeave"/>
                    </fo:block>

                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open it in IDEA IntelliJ, I get the following error message:
[image: Error message in IntelliJ]

Does anybody know what is wrong here? I cannot find a plausible explanation.

Comment: Using XSLT and XSL-FO usually is two step process, you first use an XSLT processor to transform some input XML to an XSL-FO result document, you then use an XSL-FO processor like Apache FOP to feed the XSL-FO document to it and generate PDF output. The error message you have shown sounds as if you feed your XSLT stylesheet to the XSL-FO processor.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for your response. Basically a good point but what puzzles me then is that xsl:template in line 7 is not marked as error. Also, the error appears already on the level of XSD validation, my current theory is that the FO XSD file does not allow nesting XSL which does not make sense to me.

Comment: If that is an error by a validating parser then of course you might simply want to ignore it while authoring XSLT stylesheets.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, in the end I just manipulated the XSD to avoid that confusing error message in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the XSD for FOP which I downloaded from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/fop/src/foschema/fop.xsd lacked support for nested XSL-T statements.

As a workaround, I manually added a

```
<any processContent="skip"/>
```

to that XSD file at the right place.

Comment: That doesn't feel like the right solution to me. You shouldn't expect an XSLT stylesheet to be valid against the schema for XSL-FO: rather than fixing the schema, you should be using a tool chain that doesn't attempt that spurious validation.

Comment: @MichaelKay Does not seem right to me either. I am using IDEA IntelliJ and I could not find a setting which would change that behavior. Can you maybe suggest a tool which does a better job there?

Comment: Although I use IntelliJ extensively for Java and JS work, I never use it for XML/XSLT, so I can't help directly. The tool I use for XML and XSLT work is Oxygen.